# Adding Custom Nodes in jbpm

Tags: jbpm

I recently started working  on JBPM 3.2.
        I need to add some custom nodes whose functionalities will be import, export etc.
        I did my some research and found out that in order to add Custom nodes we have two approaches.

1. To implement ActionHandler and write the Business Logic in the
   execute method.
2. To extend the Node class.

I am really confused which approach to follow, first one is quite easy to  implement ,while in the second approach I have to do a lot of work as in providing hibernate mapping etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add few functionalities then you may go with the ActionHandler. 
As it's not good to design your own node for simple tasks.

But if you have some large set of tasks to be done. Then go with the second option, as my experience is concerned you are gonna have to face difficulties in implementing the customized node.

Comment: Share your code, what kind of functionality you want to implement. Then I could suggest few more techniques.